# Trying to execute LIKE clause in sqlite3 in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, ios7

I am trying to execute LIKE clause in my sqlite3 query i.e.

```
sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormate;@"select * from table_name where column_name like '%"+%@+"%'",title];
```

Here **title** is a NSString type. having values like 6 Kt or 10 Kt or 14 Kt or 18 Kt

And in **column_name** i have values like this (**6 Kt, 10 Kt, 14 Kt**) in single statement

```
 |------------------------|
 |     column_name        |
 |------------------------|
 |   6 Kt, 10 Kt, 14 Kt   |
 | --------------------   |
 |   10 Kt, 18 Kt, 22 Kt  |
 | ---------------------  |
 |   6 Kt, 10 Kt, 24 Kt   |
 | ---------------------  |
 |   6 Kt, 14 Kt, 22 Kt   |
 | ---------------------- |
 |   6 Kt, 22 Kt, 24 Kt   | 
 | -----------------------|
```

and i try one more query like this :

```
sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from jewelryInfo where karat like '%@%%'",title];
```

with  the value of title = 6 Kt.

IT give the **values of a row starting with 6 Kt**

but when i try to use **18 Kt or 22 Kt** as a value for **title**

it doesn't give me any result

**I think it is only checking the first value of a row in this column.**

please help me, Thanks

Comment: are you sure you have row with 18 Kt or 22 Kt?

Comment: I got the solution as:- sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from jewelryInfo where karat like '%%%@%%'",title]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add a `%` before query. Also, you must use following query:

```
sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from jewelryInfo where ', '||karat like '%% %@%%'",title];
```

to match items in middle, beginning or end of list and match 6 but not 16.